# PineScript: Generate an alert on the very first bar of the day

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to generate an alert on the opening bar of the day with the previous closing value.

So my code is something like:

```
lastPrice = barstate.isrealtime ? close[1] : close
message = "My beautiful alert message of previous close price: " + str.tostring(lastPrice)
if (barstate.isfirst) 
    alert(message, alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

I am in Daily chart.

However none of the alert is generated in 9:15 AM when the Indian market opens up.

So my expectation is:

At the very first minute of the market open (say 9:15 AM), I want the alert message to be fired up.

I put the alert message setting something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`barstate.isfirst` will return `true` only for the very first bar on your chart.

If you want to detect the first bar of the day, use something like below:

`is_first_bar = ta.change(time("D"))`

Comment: I added it like this:
    is_first_bar = ta.change(time("D"))
    if (is_first_bar)  // Generate alerts only on the very first bar
        alert('hi there', alert.freq_once_per_bar)

And set the alert in 'any alert() function call'.

But when running in replay mode - nothing is coming up.
I mean no alert is popped up.

What may be the mistake.

Comment: No worries. In real market it worked! Thanks a lot.